# Do goosebumps always appear in the same spots on the skin?

Tags: physiology, skin

Often one gets goosebumps when one is cold. I am curious whether the precise location of the goosebumps on, say, one's leg changes from occurrence to occurrence or not? In case if their precise locations are always identical is there anything particular about those locations that differentiate them from other parts of one's skin?

Thus the question: do goosebumps appear at the same spots on one's body every time or their exact location changes?

Answer (score 5):

Goosebumps are caused by the contraction of the arrector pili muscles, which are attached to hair follicles. Accordingly, they appear at the same spots on one's body every time.